# How to replace a UNION in a query for a view?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, union

I have created the following query to use in a view

```
SELECT 
          *
      FROM
          customers c
      JOIN
          customer_business cb
      ON
          c.customer_id = cb.customer_id
union
SELECT 
          *
      FROM
          customers c
      LEFT JOIN
          customer_business
      ON
          business_id=NULL;
```

It makes his work perfectly. It shows all customers with the business associated, and at the end, shows all customers with the info of the business in null.

```
customer_id    |    business_id
--------------------------------
      1        |        1
      2        |        1
      2        |        2
      1        |       NULL
      2        |       NULL
      3        |       NULL
```

But the problem es that the UNION makes the view has very poor performace.

I tryed to do it with LEFT JOIN but doesnt shows al the customers with business in null, just the ones without any businesses associated

I know that the solution to speed up my view is to remove that UNION, but i cant figure out how.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's an example

```
Customer Table
  customer_id  |      name
--------------------------------
      1        |      test1
      2        |      test2
      3        |      test3


Customer_business Table
  customer_business_id   |   customer_id   |   business_id
----------------------------------------------------------
      1                  |        1        |        1
      2                  |        1        |        2
      3                  |        1        |        3
      4                  |        2        |        1
      5                  |        2        |        2

Expected query result:
  name    |   customer_id   |   business_id
----------------------------------------------------------
  test1   |        1        |        1
  test1   |        1        |        2
  test1   |        1        |        3
  test2   |        2        |        1
  test2   |        2        |        2
  test1   |        1        |      NULL
  test2   |        2        |      NULL
  test3   |        3        |      NULL
```

Comment: I don't understand the second part of the query, what's with the idbusiness=NULL condition? It would seem to join up more rows than you want. Are you trying to get all customers where there's no corresponding customer_business row?

Comment: Step 1 for improving performance is to replace select * with select just the fields you need.

Comment: Step 2 is understanding your own query and how nulls and left joins work.

Comment: The UNION operator in SQL eliminates duplicates from the result; in order to do so it must sort an intermediate result-set. If you wish to retain duplicates and avoid the sort,  use the UNION ALL operator instead.

Comment: Thanks, i now understand most of the errors that i had done.

Comment: Thanks, i now understand most of the errors that i had done.
What im trying to do is a query that gets the join bethen customers and customer_business plus all the customers with the business information in null.
Something like:
SELECT c.customer_id, c.mail, cb.business_id FROM customers c JOIN customer_business cb ON c.customer_id = cb.customer_id
UNION ALL
SELECT c.customer_id, c.mail, NULL FROM customers c;
Which is actually much better than what i had, thanks. But i would like remove the UNION from the query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating it based on the comments below and the output you want.

Note that I have used `UNION ALL` which is faster than `UNION` as `UNION` uses `DISTINCT` to get unique records which in your case doesn't apply. Also, make sure `customer_id` is PK in `Customer` table and try adding non-unique index on `customer_id` in `Customer_Business` table and it should help with performance.

```
SELECT name,
    C.customer_id,
    business_id
FROM Customer C
INNER JOIN Customer_Business CB
    ON C.customer_id = CB.customer_id
UNION ALL
SELECT name,
    C.customer_id,
    NULL
FROM Customer C
```

Comment: The second part of the query add all the customers with the business information in null. Not just the ones without a customer_business

Comment: Did you try the query I gave above? Can you give example of values you have in customers and customer_business table and the output you want?

Comment: I updated the query in the answer based on output you want. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the union which we know that is not performant the other thing that slows down you query is the statement in the second query ON idbusiness = NULL.

I propose to edit you query like this and see the performance as a view:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, idbusiness
FROM customers c
JOIN customer_business cb ON c.customer_id = cb.customer_id
UNION 
SELECT customer_id, NULL 
FROM customers c
```

**EDIT:**

Looking for an alternative you could try this, it should return the same output (i've changed null values with 0) but i don't think it's faster:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, idbusiness
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN (

SELECT customer_id, idbusiness
FROM customer_business
UNION 
SELECT 0 , 0
)b ON ( c.customer_id = b.customer_id ) 
OR (
b.idbusiness =0
)
```

Eventually you could try to put into a view only the subquery b or delete the union by putting the values 0,0 as a record in table customer_business.

Comment: You was right, it has a performance increase, but still too slow. There are any way to remove the union?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to remove the union because, for what i understood, the result of your query must contain two distinct subsets of the same table: the one with the customers and its business and the one with all the customers. I edited the answer with an alternative but i don't think it's faster.